405 Not Allowed Error on POST Request through Nginx in MERN Applicatio
I have a MERN application set up with Nginx as the reverse proxy. My containers are successfully running, and I can reach my API with GET requests through Nginx. However, when I try to make a POST request to the API through Nginx, I receive a 405 Not Allowed error.
Here’s a summary of my setup:
Nginx Configuration
nginx.conf:
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test.com;

  index index.html;
  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend:8000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}


Dockerfile for Frontend:
FROM node:19-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:1.21.0-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]


React Frontend Code:
const handleRegister = () => {
  fetch('/api/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ username, password })
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => setMessage(data.message))
  .catch(error => setMessage('Error registering: ' + error));
};


Express Backend Code:
app.post('/api/register', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;
  if (users.find(user => user.username === username)) {
    return res.status(400).json({ message: 'User already exists' });
  }
  users.push({ username, password });
  res.status(201).json({ message: 'User registered successfully' });
});


Docker-compose.yml:
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ../api
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - default 

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ../ui
    container_name: ui
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    networks:
      - default  


When I make a POST request to http://192.168.2.205/api/register directly from the frontend, it works fine, but when the same request is sent through Nginx, I get the 405 Not Allowed error.
How can I resolve this issue and make POST requests work through Nginx? Any help would be appreciated!
